# AWS IoT Create custom OTA job document

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, ota

I'm new to AWS IoT and currently exploring creating a job to update/install firmware via the AWS IoT Console custom job instead of Amazon FreeRTOS service.

My questions are:

1. What is the content in the job document(.json) in AWS IoT Console? i.e., to specify to install the firmware update for the software in AWS S3 bucket
2. Where to find out the documentation for a custom job? I found some sample using AWS IoT SDK for python or JS. Is that the correct way to create a job for my firmware device via this SDK?
3. Also, is that the alternative way to update the firmware by using device shadow instead of creating a custom job in AWS IoT Console.

I appreciate if any IoT job creation documentation or related sample link could be provided.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/using-device-jobs-for-over-the-air-updates/) which outlines about custom job based on Raspberry Pi. Additional notes for your questions.

- Typically the image source to be uploaded can be in S3. Check this [Developer notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/api-iot-CreateJob.html) provided by AWS possible content which would go into JSON
- Please check on the [developer documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/api-iot-CreateOTAUpdate.html) on creating a OTA Job.
- You can use an combination of IoT rules and Messaging infrastructure with Lambda to achieve the same. See if you can make use of the AWS forum for additional insights.